# Can you help a beginner troubleshoot setting up firebase database for javscript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I get a little help configuring firebase for a simple card catalog object lesson project? All the walk-throughs I found out there seemed to be beyond my ability until I found this `https://deanhume.github.io/firebase-example/` and the code here `https://github.com/deanhume/firebase-example/blob/master/no-auth.html`

So I understand firebase can save my objects into an array with a URL as this code shows:

```js
    var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://brilliant-fire-3159.firebaseio.com');

    var messageField = document.getElementById('messageInput');
    var messageResults = document.getElementById('results');

    function savedata(){
    var message = messageField.value;

    messagesRef.push({fieldName:'messageField', text:message});
      messageField.value = '';}
```

But I think something's going awry with with my Firebase SDK snippet. I have the URL "firebaseio.com" that's used to store the array, but I think I'm doing something wrong on initializing.

When I use the Config code, I get this error message
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

When I use the CDN code, I get `helpers.ts:72 GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?l=dataLayer net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

And when I use Automatic, I get

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:39 GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:42 GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/__/firebase/init.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

In my JS file, I put in this code:

`let firebaseArray = new Firebase('https://project-library-aa3e2.firebaseio.com');`

and then simply something like

```js
  let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  let fname = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
  let lname = document.querySelector("#lname").value;
  let pubDate = document.querySelector("#pubDate").value;
  let pages = document.querySelector("#pages").value;
  let read = document.getElementById("read").checked;
  var addBook = new Book(title, fname, lname, pubDate, pages, read);
  myLibrary.push(addBook);
  FirebaseArray.push(addBook);
```

But in my html, I can't find something like this from my firebase dashboard: `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>`

So I added as the firebase site recommended:

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of the Firebase Realtime Database SDK is very very old and no longer supported:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

And so is this code:

```
var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://brilliant-fire-3159.firebaseio.com');
```

Nothing you see in today's documentation is going to work with the stuff above.

The first thing you should do is stop using this old code, and start over using the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).  The new APIs are similar, but you should really abandon what you have now, and try to port it to the modern SDKs.

Comment: ok, that's a start so I can stop banging my head against this wall, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

woo hoo, it took me forever to unravel this, but I got some of it down.

Using this basic tutorial helped, even though it's from an earlier version of firebase:
https://techtrench.org/firebase-contact-form/

The steps are basically the same, except that instead of something as simple as
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>` before the closing  tag, initializing Firebase takes a lot more code.

It's the stuff that you get when you start a project: `Copy and paste these scripts into the bottom of your <body> tag, but before you use any Firebase services:`

One crucial step that I didn't see in documentation but was mentioned here was "switch to Real-time Database at the top, click Rules, change them to true, true and publish your changes."

Finally, by comparing the code provided in the tutorial with what I did, i realized I could not just do this to initialize:

```
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

I needed to tell it the product I wanted to use, so:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```